# Denwer ругается на file_get_contents при https

Tags: denwer, https

> <b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents()
> [<a
> href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]:
> Unable to find the wrapper
> &quot;https&quot; - did you forget to
> enable it when you configured PHP? in
> <b>Z:\home\test1.ru\www\inc\classes\test.php</b>
> on line <b>20</b><br />

Как включить поддержку https то?

Comment: Вы не один. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444249/unable-to-find-the-wrapper-https-did-you-forget-to-enable-it-when-you-config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

php.ini:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Саму либу php_openssl.dll я не помню где брал. По-моему, тянул отсюда: http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html